# ror find many records in db by parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know how to find single item with given parameter.

> @record = Record.find_by(phone: params[:phone])

How do I find all records in db with given parameter?

```
@records = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@records = Record.where(phone: params[:phone])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@records = Record.where(phone: params[:phone]).all
```